# Expressing as a sum of squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose a number can be expressed as a sum of two squares. If I know it's prime factorization, what is the easiest way to find two such numbers?
For e.g., let us consider the number $97^5 \cdot 641^3 \cdot 3^8$, how can I find $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = 97^5 \cdot 641^3 \cdot 3^8$?

Comment: Are you certain that your number isn't supposed to be a square itself? Because otherwise an example like the prime $3,232,829 = 5^2 + 1798^2$ would be very hard to decompose into a sum of squares without pure trial and error.

Comment: Once you know how to do it for primes that are $1 \bmod 4$ and squares of primes that are $3 \bmod 4$ then you can do it for any number since products of sums of squares are themselves sums of squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must do it for its prime factors by trial, then you can use [Brahmagputa's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity).

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2+2abcd-2abcd$$

$$=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$$

Notice that if $p$ is a prime number and there exist $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2+b^2=p$ then without loss of generality we can assume that $a>b$ therefore $$\displaystyle 2b^2<a^2+b^2=p \implies b^2 <\frac{p}{2} \implies b \leq \lfloor\sqrt{\frac{p}{2}}\rfloor $$ So you only need to check the first $\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{p}{2}}\rfloor$ numbers to find the smaller number $b$ in $a^2+b^2=p$, and once you've found it the other one has already been found from  $a^2 = p-b^2$.

Comment: What if one of its prime factors can't be expressed as the sum of two squares?